# Tensorflow: conditionally change values of a tensor (multiple conditions)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, conditional-statements

I get a tensor with integers `[1,3,2,5,6,3,6,10, ...]`. The integers range between 0 and 10 (including borders). (Shape `(batch_size,1)`).

Each number should be replaced with a constant float value. for Example to: `[0.25, 2.3, 1.0, 4.0,3.0,2.3,3.0,5.2,.. ]`

What is the most efficient way to map the values?